# List of Theorems and tikz overlay

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec, thmtools

Suppose you call `\listoftherems` from the `thmtools` package, and use `titlesec` package to modify appearance of chapter headings.
Suppose further that in `titleformat`, you include a simple `tikzpicture`, which you want to fill the page's header, so you use the `overlay` option.

It turns out that the ordinary table of contents and the chapter both have the correct title format, but the heading of list of theorems disappears entirely.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{thm}
%
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\gdef\TOCtitle{}}
{}
{0cm}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
    [remember picture,overlay]
    \node
        at ([yshift=-3cm]current page.north west){
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                [remember picture,overlay]
                \fill [blue!50] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,3cm);
                \node[
                    xshift = 0.5\paperwidth,
                    yshift = 1cm,
                    font = \Large
                    ]
                    {#1};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftheorems
%
\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{thm}[My Theorem]
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: page 1 - table of contents]
[image: page 2 - list of theorems]
[image: page 3 - first chapter]

However, remove the `overlay` option from both `tikzpicture` environments, and all three headings are rendered identically (though the picture is improperly positioned).

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{thm}
%
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\gdef\TOCtitle{}}
{}
{0cm}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
    [remember picture]
    \node
        at ([yshift=-3cm]current page.north west){
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                [remember picture]
                \fill [blue!50] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,3cm);
                \node[
                    xshift = 0.5\paperwidth,
                    yshift = 1cm,
                    font = \Large
                    ]
                    {#1};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftheorems
%
\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{thm}[My Theorem]
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

I don't understand why this is happening. The answer may lie in the implementation of `thmtools`, which I don't know well enough (or at all) and lack the patience to.

Comment: The remember picture option works by writing the origin locations in the aux file.  In your case, only pages 1 and 3 had their origins saved. so when overlay is specified, tikz has no idea where to put it.  So the question is, why no \pgfsysdpfmark for page 2?

Comment: This observation may be relevant: if the order of TOC and LofThms is interchanged, the problem persists: TOC and Chapter are still rendered correctly (and appear on pages 2 and 3), whilst LofThms has no header (despite being on page 1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\listoftheorems` command executes `\@fileswfalse`. I'm not sure why, the annotation in `thm-listof.dtx` is rather cryptic. However, so long as you have only one `\listoftheorems`, removing the declaration seems safe. This declaration makes it impossible for LaTeX to write the PGF mark in the `.aux` file.

I've used John Kormylo's suggestion for avoiding a picture inside a picture. I also avoided the `explicit` option that's not necessary: use a command with an argument in the last argument to `\titleformat` instead.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\listoftheorems}{\@fileswfalse}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{thm}
%
\newcommand{\tikztitleformat}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \path[fill,blue!50] (current page.north west) rectangle +(\paperwidth,-3cm);
    \node[below=1.5cm,anchor=center,font = \Large] at (current page.north) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\gdef\TOCtitle{}}
{}
{0cm}
{\tikztitleformat}
%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftheorems
%
\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{thm}[My Theorem]
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have several `\listoftheorems`. Your patch makes the headings render correctly (I am amazed!), but unfortunately only the first `\listoftheorems` is produced. Any more ideas?

Comment: @Nikita That's what I feared. I believe it's better to open a new question with a simple failing example; modifying the present one would invalidate the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't solve the problem, but at least it doesn't call tikz recursively

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \path[fill,blue!50] (current page.north west) rectangle +(\paperwidth,-3cm);
  \node[below=1.5cm,anchor=center,font = \Large] at (current page.north) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
```